# Extract multiple file elements and generate a yaml file

Tags: cmake

I have the project's root directory `CMakeLists.txt` file which contains the subdirectories to be added as `add_subdirectory('dirname' 'ALL/BASE')`. Inside each subdirectory there is it's own `CMakeLists.txt` which contains the package name and its headers, dependencies and other attributes as arguments to a standard library package call. I want to get the specific data and create a YAML file which can be further parsed for processing.

**CMakeLists.txt**(root directory):

```
add_subdirectory(sd1 ALL)
...(similar calls for - sd2, sd3, etc.)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**(subdirectory sd1):

```
... (some cmake script)
STANDARD_LIBRARY_PACKAGE([packagename] [attribute1-name] [attribute1-value(s)] [attribute2-name] [attribute2-value(s)] ... )
...(more cmake script)
```

The task is to get the subdirectories from outermost file, go into the subdir's `CMakeLists.txt` and get the ***space separated*** attribute values and create the yml file. The `STANDARD_LIBRARY_PACKAGE(args)` command is present in all the subdir files, and needs the

**yml format :**

```
packagename1
- attribute-name: attribute-values
- package-path: path/to/subdir
packagename2
-
- ...(similar more)
```

I tried this with Python, but I am unable to get the attribute values as some are based on conditional states (if CMake variable set then use it else don't)

**Things I tried :**

```
macro (show_args)
#  set(multiValueArgs DEPENDENCIES)
  message("${${}ARGV0}")
  message("${${}ARGV}")
endmacro()


function (ROOT_STANDARD_LIBRARY_PACKAGE)
  show_args()
endfunction()


ROOT_STANDARD_LIBRARY_PACKAGE(Genetic
                              HEADERS Math/GeneticMinimizer.h
                              DICTIONARY_OPTIONS "-writeEmptyRootPCM"
                              DEPENDENCIES Core MathCore TMVA)
```

**Current output :**

```
Genetic
Genetic;HEADERS;Math/GeneticMinimizer.h;DICTIONARY_OPTIONS;-writeEmptyRootPCM;DEPENDENCIES;Core;MathCore;TMVA
```

**Expected output :**

```
Genetic
- path: /path/to/file/directory
- deps: (all the DEPENDENCIES)
```

How can I do this manipulation with cmake script.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your intention is (relatively) clear, generating the YAML file with needed info consist from several steps, **weakly linked** with each other. Such as: collecting arguments in CMake, appending information into single file from several places, creating valid YAML. But on Stack Overflow we want a question with a **specific problem** in it. "I tried with file, string and cmake_parse_arguments from cmake commands but couldn't get it working." - What **exactly** (which step) you couldn't get working? Add this information into the question post (by [edit]ing it).

Comment: BTW, multiline code formatting could be easily achive by selecting the code and using `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the clarification. I am trying to understand the cmake script usage. It would be helpful if I could get some guidelines about which cmake commands can be used for the task.

Comment: Do not paste links to your code into the question, paste the **code itself** (as text, and format it appropriately). Also describe, what is exactly wrong/unclear with your code's behavior. E.g., "I want the code to give this results, but it give that results". In case of `cmake_parse_arguments` command you may start with its [documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added my approach here, any guidelines.?

Comment: Your expected output is not valid YAML. You cannot have a colon followed by space in an unquoted scalar string. Or isn't it your intention to have a single multi-line scalar in the expected output and did you forget to put a colon after `Genetic`?

Comment: @Anthon yes.. sorry, there is a colon after Genetic, and I wrote a macro to get desired values and used FILE operations (write,append) from cmake script to get the yml files.